# Removing all sublists containing any arbitrary string as one or more of its list component

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

so, basically I have a list of sublists of varying length. For example,

```
list={{#,a,b,c,d},{#,e,f,g},{#,h,1},{#,2},{#},{#,k,l,m,n,o},{#,a,b,1,2},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5}}
```

And I would like to end up with

```
listFiltered={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5}}
```

So, what I would like to filter out is all the sublist containing any string.
Now, instead of filtering for any sublist containing any string, I also know that each sublist that I want to filter out has the "#" character as its first sublist element.

This is then the repeating pattern, a "#" character as the first element of every sublist of arbitrary length, that contains a string somewhere, and therefore should be removed from the main list.

How should I go about achieving this? I have tried a number of things with DeleteCases and StringMatchQ but couldn't really get the syntax right.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Cases[{__Integer}] @ list
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

```
DeleteCases[{"#",___}] @ list
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

```
DeleteCases[{"#", ___}|{___,_Symbol,___}] @ list
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

```
Cases[Except[{"#" ,___}|{___,_Symbol,___}]] @ list
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Comment: Thank you! This works! The only part I need to change is put "#" instead of just # since the characters in the lists are apparently "#".

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"#", a, b, c, d}, {"#", e, f, g}, {"#", h, 1}, {"#", 
    2}, {"#"}, {"#", k, l, m, n, o}, {"#", a, b, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 
    3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};

Pick[list, MemberQ[Except[__Integer]] /@ list, False]

Extract[list, Position[list, {__Integer}]]

SequenceReplace[list, k : {{___, Except[_Integer], ___}} :> Nothing]

Pick[list, NoneTrue[Head@# =!= Integer &] /@ list]

Pick[list, AllTrue[Head@# === Integer &] /@ list]
```

---

*Result*

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{"#", a, b, c, d}, {"#", e, f, g}, {"#", h, 1}, 
   {"#", 2}, {"#"}, {"#", k, l, m, n, o}, {"#", a, b, 1, 2}, 
   {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
```

Quote from the question:

*"I also know that each sublist that I want to filter out has the #
character as its first sublist element"*

This translates into the following pattern:

```
p = {"#", ___};
```

Some additional solutions

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {p}]

SequenceReplace[list, {p} :> Nothing]

Delete[Position[p] @ list] @ list

MapAt[Nothing, Position[p] @ list] @ list

list /. p :> Nothing
```

All return

{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"#", a, b, c, d}, {"#", e, f, g}, {"#", h, 1}, {"#", 2},
        {"#"}, {"#", k, l, m, n, o}, {"#", a, b, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, 
        {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {__Integer}} :> s]

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases` and `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteElements[#, SequenceCases[#, {s : {str_String, ___}} :> s]] &@list

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}*)
```

A variant using `Pick` with `MatchQ`:

```
Pick[#, MatchQ[#, {__Integer}] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}*)
```